# Getting min value from a list using python

Tags: python, list

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I keep getting an **Index error** whenever I try to run the code.

```
def min_valueinlist(bag = [1,-1,3,4,5,6]):
    bag_length= len(bag)
    counter = 1
    min_value = bag[0]
    while counter <= bag_length:
        v = bag[counter]
        if (v < min_value):
            min_value = v
        else:
            pass
        counter=counter+1
    return min_value
    

print(min_valueinlist())
```

Comment: There's a built-in [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#min) function...

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) | *Always share the full stack trace* when you're asking about an error.

Comment: You really should use a for loop here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As arrays are `0-indexed`, the last index is 1 off the length

```
values  [1, -1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
indices  0   1  2  3  4  5  # and len() is 6
```

---

- so your loop should use `<` and not `<=`
- `else:pass` is useless
- there is a buitin [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#min)

```
while counter < bag_length: # and not <=
```

---

When you need to iterate on values only and don't need their indices, prefer a `for` loop

```
def min_valueinlist(bag=[1, -1, 3, 4, 5, 6]):
    min_value = bag[0]
    for v in bag:
        if v < min_value:
            min_value = v
    return min_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Python already has a `min()` function that does this for you:

```
# Creating a function that takes one parameter
def get_minumum_value_in_list(list):
    return min(list)  # Returning the minimum value in the list using min()


print(min([1, -1, 3, 4, 5, 6])) # Executing function
```